Google OAuth2 redirect_uri_mismatch error in Production but Works Locally
I'm working on a project where I need to update an organization's Google Drive token using OAuth2 authentication. My code works perfectly on my local machine, but when I deploy it to the server, I encounter an invalid error redirect_url. Here is the relevant part of my code:
def update_drive_gtoken(
    data: schema.UpdateDriveToken,
    sql: Session,
    auth_token: frontendModel.FrontendToken,
    organization: model.Organization
):
    """
    Update organization drive token
    """
    organization_user = sql.query(model.RegisterUserOrganization).filter_by(
        user_id=auth_token.user_id,
        org_uid=organization.id,
        is_active=True,
        is_deleted=False
    ).first()

    if not organization_user:
        CustomValidations.raize_custom_error(
            error_type="not_exist",
            msg="user does not belong to this organization"
        )

    token_json = None
    if auth_token.user_id == organization.admin_id:
        if data.code is not None:
            CLIENT_ID = "1234.com"
            CLIENT_SECRET = "FXXC"
            REDIRECT_URL = "http://localhost:3000"

            token_url = 'https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token'
            token_data = {
                'code': data.code,
                'client_id': CLIENT_ID,
                'client_secret': CLIENT_SECRET,
                'redirect_uri': REDIRECT_URL,
                'grant_type': 'authorization_code'
            }

            token_response = requests.post(token_url, data=token_data, timeout=80, verify=False)
            token_json = token_response.json()
            extracted_token = {
                'access_token': token_json.get('access_token'),
                'refresh_token': token_json.get('refresh_token'),
                'client_id': CLIENT_ID,
                'client_secret': CLIENT_SECRET,
                'expires_in': (datetime.utcnow() + timedelta(seconds=token_json['expires_in'])).isoformat(),
                'scope': token_json.get('scope'),
                'token_uri': token_url
            }

            if token_response.status_code != 200:
                CustomValidations.raize_custom_error(
                    error_type="invalid",
                    loc="code",
                    msg="Failed to exchange token. Please provide a valid Google token.",
                    inp=str(data.code),
                    ctx={"code": "valid"},
                )

            if organization.gtoken is not None:
                CustomValidations.raize_custom_error(
                    error_type="already_exist",
                    msg=f"token already exists in {organization.title}"
                )

            organization.gtoken = json.dumps(token_json)
            sql.commit()

            return {"organization": organization, "token": extracted_token}

When I run this code locally, the token exchange works without any issues. However, on the server, I get the following error message:"invalid redirect_url" I'm not sure why this mismatch is happening only in production. Has anyone faced a similar issue or knows how to resolve this? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

What is the redirect uri it is saying is missing

Thank you for your response.
When we create credentials in the Google Developer Console, the redirect URI is included as part of the credentials setup. This URI is specified during the configuration process and is used for the OAuth2 authentication flow.

I have added both my production and local URLs, but I am still encountering the same error. Do you have any ideas on what might be wrong?
